# How to use done callback without passing event in jquery-file-upload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to implement basic plus UI and I encounter this issue. I am calling done callback function under `jquery-fildupload-ui.js` but I do not have any event to pass to argument `e` therefore I pass `null` value. The snippet below is the first three lines of that fuction. Because I pass `null` value to the argument `e`, I hit **"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "**

```
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
   return false;
}
```

I am not very good with javascript. Could anyone help me out with this and how I should approach to prevent this? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What I have done so far is that I create a mock event and pass it down just to satisfy the API.